# Unity c#: making an array of class type equal to FindObjectOfType

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my c# script I am working on, I have this code

```
 public class Attractor : MonoBehaviour {

 public Rigidbody rb;

 private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     //physics code
     Attractor[] attractors = FindObjectOfType<Attractor>();
 }
```

I am currently getting an error saying

> Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Attractor' to 'Attractor[]'

What should I do to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want FindObject**s**OfType

```
Attractor[] attractors = FindObjectsOfType<Attractor>();
```